# How to use lottie animation in flutter app?

Tags: animation, flutter, lottie

I want to animate the Lottie file in the flutter app.
I tried searching every corner of the internet and failed to find any info on it.

I found out that there is a flutter package "flutter_lottie.dart" and has a function to animate.

There is also an example provided by the author about the usage of the `flutter_lottie.dart`

but this I tried running the exact example : [flutter Lottie example](https://github.com/CameronStuartSmith/flutter_lottie/tree/master/example)

and it gave the same error:

```
Creating Method Channel convictiontech/flutter_lottie_0
E/flutter (11371): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(199)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (11371): PlatformException(error, java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to parse 
composition
E/flutter (11371):  at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView$2.onResult(LottieAnimationView.java:68)
```

How to use animate using Lottie in flutter?

Comment: did you add flutter lottie package to your project ? [link](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_lottie)

Comment: yes! it's there

Comment: you can use rive instead of lottie it`s very better than lottie and has an online editor you can import your lottie file to this platform and export it as rive https://rive.app/ add this package https://pub.dev/packages/flare_flutter and follow this tutorial https://medium.com/flutterdevs/flutter-animation-with-flare-3863e8ff5030

Comment: yes! I can do that but I need to develop the animation in after effects and place it in flutter app.

Comment: exactly you can develop animations in after effect and export your animation as flottie then import flottie animation in rive and export as flare format

Comment: what is flottie.  can you provide the link?

Comment: sry i mean lottie

Comment: ok, but how to import Lottie to rive, I tried but the animation won't play!

Comment: check this [link](https://twitter.com/rive_app/status/1169294765625618432?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed%7Ctwterm%5E1169295889027874816&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.redditmedia.com%2Fmediaembed%2Fcznvcp%3Fresponsive%3Dtrue%26is_nightmode%3Dfalse)

Comment: I tried this, the animation won't play. I am dragging the `JSON` file from Lottie to rive and then again dragging the imported file to the canvas. Now it shows the shapes but animation not playing.

Comment: do you go to animation tab ? you should go to animation tab select animation and then click play

Comment: can you make this work! https://lottiefiles.com/15130-linkedin-logo

Comment: yeah but 5 hours later

Comment: ok! I this only this file has a problem, some works but some don't.

Comment: lottie is not stable in flutter i have many problem with lotties but rive is a great animation platform for flutter and i suggest you to learn work with rive

Comment: https://rive.app/a/veneno/files/flare/linkedin/preview

Answer (score 8):

The [lottie package](https://pub.dev/packages/lottie) is a pure Flutter/Dart implementation of a Lottie Player.
It is a direct port of [Lottie-Android](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android) and support the same set of features.

Include this in your pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  lottie:
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:lottie/lottie.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Lottie.asset('assets/lottiefile.json'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Pub: https://pub.dev/packages/lottie
Github: https://github.com/xvrh/lottie-flutter

Comment: what does this means `This repository is a unofficial conversion of the Lottie-android library in pure Dart.` in the pub?

Comment: The library is a direct port of Lottie-Android: the Java code was copied file-by-file and converted to Dart/Flutter (no architecture change). 
Unofficial: I don't have any contact with the original author

Comment: This docs also say, `The performance is not great and some features are missing.`. I want to show a lot of animation, can I rely on this?

Comment: That part of the doc is related to Web compilation. For iOS/Android, the performance should be ok (similar to the original libraries). The performance really depends on the animation itself. Some animations are really expensive (with lots of elements, lots of gradients etc...) some are really cheap to draw. Please experiment with it and report any problem you have.

Comment: how to load lottie files before the app run
i have used didchangedepenedencies but getting some error

Answer (score 2):

you can animation download in **gif format** from lottiefiles website and **open** with **Image.assets** **or** 
in **json format**

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
   @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
      children: [
        // Load a Lottie file from your assets
        Lottie.asset('assets/LottieLogo1.json'),

        // Load a Lottie file from a remote url
        Lottie.network(
            'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xvrh/lottie- 
       flutter/master/example/assets/Mobilo/A.json'),

        // Load an animation and its images from a zip file
        Lottie.asset('assets/lottiefiles/angel.zip'),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

Comment: I have a lottie in folder, assets/lottie/lottie.json, but I got an error unable to load asset, how do I fix it ?

Comment: You must add assets to pubspec.xml

Comment: @RohmatulLaily Did you path the file and add it to the pubspec.yaml?